# Enable navigation buttons and pagination in Swiperjs - vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, swiper.js

I made a slider with a swiper.js in vuejs

everything works fine but the navigation buttons and pagination don't work

I set the `:navigation="true"` and `:pagination="{clickable:true, dynamicBullets:true}"` but they still don't work

where is the problem?

What else should I do?

```
<template>
        <Swiper 
                class="rounded-xl text-xs w-[95%]"    
                :modules="[ SwiperEffectCreative]"    
                :slides-per-view="2"      
                :space-between="20"
                :navigation="true"
                :pagination="{clickable:true, dynamicBullets:true}"
                :autoplay="{delay: 3000,disableOnInteraction: true,}" >


          <SwiperSlide v-for="(product, index) in data" :key='index' class="py-6">
            <ProductCard :data="product"/>
          </SwiperSlide>

        </Swiper>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to fix it

I should have added the `SwiperNavigation` in the modules.

```
:modules="[ SwiperEffectCreative, SwiperNavigation]"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on SwiperJS, but according to their docs it seems Navigation and Pagination are modules. This means they need to be both imported into your component logic and included in the "modules" prop. It's also good practice in Vue to bind your props in the setup function for better code readability. Finally, `EffectCreative` is the correct name of that module (without "Swiper").

```
<template>
  <Swiper
    class="rounded-xl text-xs w-[95%]"
    :modules="[EffectCreative, Navigation, Pagination]"
    :slides-per-view="2"
    :space-between="20"
    :navigation="true"
    :pagination="{ clickable: true, dynamicBullets: true }"
    :autoplay="{ delay: 3000, disableOnInteraction: true }"
  >
    <SwiperSlide v-for="(product, index) in data" :key="index" class="py-6">
      <ProductCard :data="product" />
    </SwiperSlide>
  </Swiper>
</template>

<script>
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/vue";
import { EffectCreative, Navigation, Pagination } from "swiper";
</script>
```

Or to bind props in your setup method:

```
<Swiper
  :modules="modules"
  :pagination="pagination"
  ...
>

<script>
import {...};

setup(){
 return {
  const modules = [ EffectCreative, Navigation, Pagination ];
  const pagination = { clickable: true, dynamicBullets: true };
 }
}
</script>
```